# Is there any fast library(s) for finding human eyes and mouth in Flash? (Actionscript)

Tags: actionscript-3, computer-vision, detection, face-detection

So I have real time video stream. With 1 (one) person on It . It Is Black and White, I need to be able to capture this persons eyes and mouth (direction (at least X,Y), state (at least opened or closed) )

So Is there any fast library(s) for finding human eyes and mouth in Flash in such case? (pure Actionscript or Haxe\Java\C++\C port in SWC form...)

What do I know Is - some libs are described in this presentation http://www.bytearray.org/?p=1040&cpage=1#comment-330183

Grate example for eyes is here http://play.blog2t.net/files/black-or-white/

Source for Face detection (AS3) http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000687.php#comments

Way to find mouth and eyes http://web.media.mit.edu/~jackylee/attention.htm

But I have never seen mouth detection...(

Starting points are not what I need at all. I need some working Open-Source CODE examples and SWC librarys.=)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Eugene Zatepyakin](http://blog.inspirit.ru/?p=416) has done impressive progress on this, do check that out.

[image]
<sub>(source: [inspirit.ru](http://blog.inspirit.ru/wp-content/uploads/facedetect/face_detect_620.png))</sub>

Comment: да ну! :) that dude's brilliant

Answer (score 1):

I'd look into the face detection algorithms that digital cameras use. In addition, [this looked like a GREAT starting point](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/CRV.2009.48) for you since somebody else has already done it and here is the official technical article that goes along with it.

Comment: Starting points are not what I need at all. I need some working Opensource CODE examples and librarys.

Answer (score 1):

Can Flash call out to other libraries (I have no experience in this)?  If so, you can use the OpenCV libraries for face detection.

Comment: nope.. not directly... but there is some port... And I ve never seen how to detect MOUTH with it...?)