# How to detec face, eyes, lips in flash as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, detection

Pls help me, I want demo detec face, eyes, lips on image but i research not found.

Thank all!!!![image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any fast library(s) for finding human eyes and mouth in Flash? (Actionscript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564526/is-there-any-fast-librarys-for-finding-human-eyes-and-mouth-in-flash-actions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a library like the Oddcast Face Detection API, which tracks points like the eyes, the nose and the chin. 
http://www.oddcast.com/dev/facedetectionAPI/

You need to buy a license for this API.

There are a couple of other libraries for face detection with Flash, but this is the only one so far that tracks different features, like the eyes.