# implementing facial lock feature in android app

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, face-detection

i want to implement the face-lock feature for my application  but couldn't get to a start. their is lot of material over OpenCV and javaCV but i really don't know where to start and i even don't know is it really possible for us to implement face lock personally.

i am a beginner in android face detection so any kind of help will be highly appreciated ..i tried on OpenCV and javaCV homepage but couldn't understand .

i searched much over here too but couldn't get to some understandable information ..

Comment: try Doing some R&D with this link it might help you [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020992/how-to-detec-face-eyes-lips-in-flash-as3/19023021#19023021)

Answer (score -1):

Face matching is not possible in android as of now as it only measures the shape of face whether round, ellipsoid or oval but could not differentiate between two similar oval/round/ellipsoid faces.

Comment: but apps like [FaceLock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facelock4appspro) are providing the feature